# IllegalArgumentException IN ANDROID URL

Tags: android, urlencode

Using the below url I got an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 47: http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/{userid}/locations?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}.
```

URL:

```
URL=http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/{userid}/locations?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}
```

how  to solve the error. I don't have good knowledge in URL encoding. please help me to find the solution.

Comment: character 47 is a left brace, it's invalid, encode it

Comment: You should replace {userid} by a userId, something like 123

Comment: You should replace `{userid}` with values. That are only placeholder

Comment: just a guess, maybe you're missing a dollar sign `$` before the curly braces? if not, post the stack trace for someone to help you better

Comment: you can also try encoding your url `String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;`

Comment: thanks jens..that works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually it is looking for long/integer value and you are passing a `{` just put a `$` so that it will be replaced by the actual value pointed by the variable

http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/1/locations?lat=5&lng=5

your Address is like this

```
URL=http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/{userid}/locations?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}
```

it should be like this

```
 URL=http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/${userid}/locations?lat=${latitude}&lng={longitude}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not use some special characters in URL, so we have to replace these special characters with its encoded form.
Replace your URL with following URL

```
URL=http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/%7Buserid%7D/locations?lat=%7Blatitude%7D&lng=%7Blongitude%7D
```

May this help you.

Comment: Also refer to this link to encode/decode url 
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 0):

URLEncoder should be the way to go. You only need to keep in mind to encode only the individual query string parameter name and/or value, not the entire URL, for sure not the query string parameter separator character & nor the parameter name-value separator character =.

```
String q = "replace_with user_id/locations?lat=replace with latitude&lng=replace with longitude";
String url = "http://safetracker-threetinker.rhcloud.com/api/=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: please use this in my url